# How can I convert a muffin recipe to make crumpets?

Tags: baking, bread, muffins

If I have a recipe that I like for muffins (in the original English sense of the word, i.e. a fat disc of bread that's made from cooking a yeasted batter on a griddle in crumpet rings), what do I have to do to convert it to make [crumpets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crumpet) instead? Looks like I need more hydration (maybe 120% instead of 100%) and to use plain flour instead of bread flour, but is there anything else?

(The muffin recipe in question is from Peter Reinhart's *Artisan Bread Everyday*. Except that he calls them English muffins, because he's American.)

Comment: May I ask why you don't just find a crumpet recipe?

Comment: I have a couple of crumpet recipes, but I really like the muffins from the muffin recipe, so I'd like to try the conversion.

Comment: But by changing the muffin recipe, you may very well be changing the aspects of it you like. In any case, I'd suggest you compare the muffin recipe to the crumpet, alter matching ingredients accordingly, and add where necessary (I'm thinking baking powder).

Comment: Feel free to head over to chat if you want to discuss - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan

Answer (score 2):

English muffins and crumpets are very similar, the only difference being that crumpets are wetter to allow the bubbles to rise out of the side off the heat. Without seeing a specific recipe, it's hard to know exactly what adjustments to make, as some muffin recipes are also quite wet.

If you think your muffin dough is wet enough, you could just try cooking it as crumpets. If it doesn't bubble correctly on top, try making it a little bit wetter until it works.